# jQuery function don't run to show "Modal" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want put a button in a web page and show a modal when yo click on it .
i wrote OnClick event function with jQuery.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modalbody">
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/modal.js"></script>
<script>

    $("btnNewGroup").on("click",function () {
        $.get("/Admin/PageGroups/Create", function (result) {
            $("Modal").modal();
            $("ModalLabel").html("Create new group");
            $("modalbody").html(result);
        })
    });
</script>
```

}

and there is references before render section :

```
 <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: Make sure jquery is *before* bootstrap.  Check in your console (browser F12), they'll probably be an error message.

Comment: Regarding your code, check out https://learn.jquery.com/ - you're missing the `id` selector in all your selectors `$("Modal")` -> `$("#Modal")` etc

Comment: Besides missing selector prefix, you should also wrap your code within document's `ready` method.

Comment: guys thank you for your answers
I did what you said and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your jquery selector. You are missing ID selector.
Please check below.

```
$("#btnNewGroup").on("click",function () {
    $.get("/Admin/PageGroups/Create", function (result) {
        $("#Modal").modal();
        $("#ModalLabel").html("Create new group");
        $("#modalbody").html(result);
    })
});
```